# How can I delete multiple emails on the HTC One X?

Tags: email, htc-one-x

I just got the HTC One X and I cannot find a way to select all my emails and delete them in one go. I have to select them one by one the delete them, after which I have to repeat the process again the clear the trash bin. I had the HTC Desire before and that did it with no problems.

Has anyone found a solution or am I missing something?

Comment: What email client are you using? The default one?

Answer (score 2):

You should do the following:

1. select one e-mail (check mark next to the mail)
2. click on "menu" (top right corner) and "select all"
3. now you can delete all emails

Comment: Unfortunately not able to locate any select all option in menu for using gmail. Thanks
Anuj